# SetTimeInterval between 2 conditions not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to trigger setTimeInterval between 2 conditions. The condition :

```
if(sentence.indexOf('Word') != -1){
 //settimeInterval for this case (1st case)
}else{
 //settimeInterval for  this  case(2nd case)
}
```

OnReady the function goes inside 2nd case ,since it returns -1. After some time  I will set a value to the sentence that is returning 0, but somehow its not going inside the  first case.
Do I need to clearTimeInterval?
 Code:

```
if(this.dateInterval.indexOf('Word') !== -1){
      console.log("Goes to case 1");
        setInterval(() => {
         console.log(this.dateInterval.indexOf('Word'));
       },3000);
    }else{
      console.log("Goes to case 2");
        setInterval(() => {
         console.log(this.dateInterval.indexOf('Word'));//logging  -1 and  0 
       },3000);
    }
```

Comment: use strict comparisson !== instead of != , just a tip

Comment: What is `settimeInterval `? Do you mean [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)?

Comment: Maybe share the whole code ?  Where does it go wrong

Comment: Apart from what @VLAZ suggests, are you executing the code you posted in the question everytime `sentence` changes its value? If not, you will never pass through the code in the 1st case.

Comment: Yes setInterval. I will  share my code..

Comment: If the sentence is changing more than once, you might have to clear the previous setIntervals

Comment: Calling `setInterval` a second time will not clear the first interval; you have to do that yourself.

Comment: @ChrisG , I treid killing the 1st interval before entering into  other setInterval. Its not  working

Comment: Put the changed code in the question and we can check for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yep, you must clear first one before start another. something like this

```
clearInterval(timer2);
let timer1 = setInterval(() => console.log(1), 2000);

clearInterval(timer1);
let timer2 = setInterval(() => console.log(2), 2000);
```

Comment: How  can I do that  inside  if  condition ?

Comment: put variables to the top and use them inside if condition? like that

```let timer1, timer2;

if(sentence.indexOf('Word') != -1){
  clearInterval(timer2);
  timer1 = setInterval(() => console.log(1), 2000);
}else{
  clearInterval(timer1);
  timer2 = setInterval(() => console.log(2), 2000);
}```

Answer (score 2):

Why not

```
setInterval(() => {
   if (sentence.indexOf('Word') !== -1) { 
       // do something
   } else {
       // do something else
   }
}, timeout);
```